# Where is the DEBUG macro defined?

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

When I run code such as the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"debug");
#else
    NSLog(@"here");
#endif
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I see "debug" printed in the log, but I did not define `DEBUG` explicitly. Where is it defined?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is most likely defined in your Build Settings under Preprocessor Macros.

Here is an example from one of my projects
[image: Here is an example from one of my projects]